# Checking triangle inequality on product of two metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose p $\in$ [1,∞) and (M1,d1) and (M2,d2) are metric spaces.
Define e(x,y) = ($[d_1(x_1,y_1)]^p +[d_2(x_2,y_2)]^p)^{1/p}$ for each x = (x1,x2) and y = (y1, y2) $\in$ M1 × M2. I need to show that e is a metric on M1 × M2.

I checked first two axioms. But I could not finish triangle inequality for p. I couldn't show $d_1(x_1,y_1)^p \leq d_1(x_1,z_1)^p+ d_1(z_1,y_1)^p$. How can I show that? If I can show that than I can use Minkowsky inequality and finish the proof.

I checked the previous posts as well but any hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can't show that $d1(x1,y1)^p≤d1(x1,z1)^p+d1(z1,y1)^p$ because it doesn't hold generally. ($A + B \ge C \not\rightarrow A^x +B^x \ge C^x$. I would suggest showing that $f(x) \ge 0$ for $x \ge 1$ if $f(x) = (A ^x + N^x)^\frac1x + (B ^x + M^x)^\frac1x - ((A + B)^x + (N + M)^x)^\frac1x$.